# Function of に in お話を聞くに?

Tags: particle-に

「……それで。扉の外でお話を聞く**に**、何だか琴里さんがトチ狂っていやがったようなので一撃お見舞いしてやったわけですが……オーケイでした？」

Hi. The speaker heard 琴里 talking in an insane way so the speaker snapped 琴里 out of it with a single stroke.

Hi. What is the function of the に in bold? Is something omitted after the に like つけ?

Thank you.